# Quick reference for statistics

Tags: references

Some Quick References for statistics.
**conditions**:
1- offline, i.e., independent from internet
2- soft-copy, i.e., (workable on a computer) not a hard-copied book or etc
3- intermediate to advanced a comprehensive
4- not an encyclopedia with many links to that page or other term
5- ...
6- free or almost free
7- reliable and professional
8- general, i.e., not dependent to specific software or package
9- ...
10- well classified terms
11- some you add.
By the way, I don't think the list of conditions is too long. That is what I and you need.
**Updates:**
Find a prefect answer which is given bellow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the "[Probability and Statistics Cookbook](http://statistics.zone/)" by Matthias Vallentin.